# Generic "nested members" trait

Tags: scala, generics

I am building a class composed of multiple traits, one of which provides the capability to include a list of "members" of the class:

```scala
trait WithNestedMembers[T] {
  val members = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]
}

class MainClass extends WithNestedMembers[MainClass] {
  // ...
}
```

This seems to work fine.

Now, I would like to use the "nesting" capability in other traits:

```scala
trait NestingUser {
  this: WithNestedMembers[NestingUser] =>
  var nestedValue = 0
  def sumNested = nestedValue + members.map(_.nestedValue).sum
}
```

The definition seems to work fine by itself. However, I cannot use this as part of `MainClass`. The following gives an error:

```
class MainClass extends WithNestedMembers[MainClass] with NestingUser {
  // Illegal inheritance, self-type MainClass does not conform to WithNestedMembers[NestingUser]
}
```

I suspect that I need to use some sort of type bounds somewhere, to explain that `WithNestedMembers[MainClass]` is good enough for requirement `WithNestedMembers[NestingUser]`. But where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying making `T` [covariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html#covariance) with `+T` like so

```
trait WithNestedMembers[+T] {
  val members = List.empty[T]
}
```